# Extensionless URL in ASP.NET 4.0 on IIS6

Tags: asp.net, url, iis

I have a ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms webapp running on a IIS6 webserver. I'm not allowed to make any changes to the webserver. I have a flex app embedded in this file called:

myapp.contoso.com/mysubapp/mysubapp.aspx

I'd like to only require the user to use the URL:

myapp.constoso.com/mysubapp

to reach the application and essentially hid the mysubapp.aspx permanently. I've been checking out URLRewrite and URLRewriting.net... It all looks to be a little much for this once instance in which I need it (if I need to add more rewrites in the future I'll use one of those frameworks). Is there a simple way to achieve this? I've checked out similar posts... it seems that I may need to write a simple one myself?

[URL Rewriting using iis6 with no extensionless urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540596/httpmodule-url-rewriting-using-iis6-with-no-extensionless-urls)

[How to deal with extensionless Url in ASP.Net and IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788985/how-to-deal-with-extensionless-url-in-asp-net-and-iis6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing I can think of is to rename your web page from `mysubapp.aspx` to `default.aspx`. This will allow users to request `myapp.constoso.com/mysubapp` and get your page. This should work if you have not removed `default.aspx` from the default document list in IIS.

Alternatively, you can add `mysubapp.aspx` to the list of default documents in IIS.

Comment: I'll just change the page to default.aspx as I don't think the admins will add the default document list. Thanks! Hopefully we move to IIS7+ soon or they allow me to use those rewriting modules.